# .htaccess redirect by url arguments

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

There are settings for nginx server:

```
location ~* ^/([a-z][a-z])-([a-z][a-z])/(.*) {
    set $args $args&COUNTRY=$1&LANGUAGE=$2;
    rewrite ^/([a-z][a-z])-([a-z][a-z])/(.*) / break;
    resolver        127.0.0.1;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1/$3$is_args$args;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```

It works for nginx.
All pages as http://localdomain.com/**-**/about/ opening as localdomain.com/about/ this page. And in url i had localdomain.com/en-en/about/  - This is what I need.

But it does not work in apache.
How to adapt it under apache in .htaccess file?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^\/([a-z][a-z])-([a-z][a-z])\/(.*)$
 RewriteRule ^([a-z][a-z])-([a-z][a-z])/(.*)$ http://localdomain.com/$3?COUNTRY=$1&LANGUAGE=$2 [R=301,L]
```

It does not work.

Comment: I think you want to be matching against `%{REQUEST_URI}` instead of `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}`.

Comment: No, unfortunately it did not help.

Comment: Interesting, those rules work for me (if I use request_uri).